# Calendar.getTime() fails with java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:MINUTE for Asia/Singapore timezone

Tags: java, date, calendar, timezone

Why is this code failing? The purpose was to remove the time part.

```
String dateStr = "1982-01-01";
String timeZoneID = "Asia/Singapore";

DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date = dateFormat.parse(dateStr);      

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZoneID));
calendar.setLenient(false);
calendar.setTime(date);
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

System.out.println(calendar.getTime());
```

The error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MINUTE
    at java.util.GregorianCalendar.computeTime(GregorianCalendar.java:2482)
    at java.util.Calendar.updateTime(Calendar.java:2265)
    at java.util.Calendar.getTimeInMillis(Calendar.java:1049)
    at java.util.Calendar.getTime(Calendar.java:1022)
    at Prog.main(Prog.java:31)
```

It works fine for the following input:

- dateStr = "1982-01-01", timeZoneID = "Europe/Berlin"
- dateStr = "1981-01-01", timeZoneID = "Asia/Singapore"
- dateStr = "1982-01-01", timeZoneID = "Asia/Seoul"

Comment: Because Singapore standard time "started" on 1/1/82? http://www.math.nus.edu.sg/aslaksen/teaching/timezone.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code starts with the date 1/1/1982 and sets both HOUR_OF_DAY and MINUTE to 0.

But there was no 12:00:00 AM on January 1, 1982, in Singapore. After 11:59:59 PM on December 31, 1981, Singapore jumped ahead by half an hour to 12:30 AM. It had previously been at UTC+7:30, but moved to the whole-hour zone of UTC+8.

Sources: [Singapore Standard Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singapore_Standard_Time) and [timeanddate.com](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/timezone.html?n=236&syear=1980). See also [*Why is Singapore in the "wrong" time zone?*](http://www.math.nus.edu.sg/aslaksen/teaching/timezone.html) for a brief history of time in Singapore.