# Hibernate - Getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:MINUTE for Asia/Singapore timezone

Tags: hibernate, timezone

Relevant to this ticket [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14968483/calendar-gettime-fails-with-java-lang-illegalargumentexceptionminute-for-asia), our application which uses Spring Hibernate that connects to a MySQL database with `serverTimezone=Asia/Singapore`, is getting the same error, when a date column has the value of  '01/01/1981'

Suggestion in that question is to use `Calendar` to navigate through the issue, however in our case, the error is thrown from Hibernate.

Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: What hibernate version do you use?

Comment: It is running on Spring 4.2 with Hibernate 5.1.4

Comment: And could you please also provide the full stacktrace.